# headphones working while booting from live USB but not when booting from hd

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, live-usb, headset

I have a headset, SONY WI-C200, that I have been using with my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. Not too long ago, all of the sudden, the headset stopped connecting to the laptop. However, if I run Ubuntu from my USB, the headset connects to the laptop and works completely fine.
Is there any way to keep or copy the connection configuration while Ubuntu is running from the USB and then use it when booting from my hd?

Thank u !

Comment: Hello. How is the headset connected to the computer? Bluetooth or 3.5 jack or USB connector?

Comment: just Bluetooth, this headset does not even have the 3.5 jack